# Is there a VSTS extension point for the account level hub group?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

Is it possible to create a hub group as part of the account level hub group? I know I can add a collection admin hub group: `ms.vss-web.collection-admin-hub-group` (under the settings gear). I'm trying to add one after 'Users'. I searched, but I couldn't find anything pointing to this, so I'm not sure if it isn't possible or if the documentation is incomplete?

[image: VSTS Account Hub Group]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to add an extension with hub group shown after Users.

`ms.vss-web.collection-admin-hub-group` is already for account level hub group. But it only can be shown under settings.

And you can refer [Hubs and hub groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/targets/overview?view=vsts#hubs-and-hub-groups) for all the available hubs and hub groups in VSTS:

[image]